# Update password not working

Tags: java, jdbc

My update password query is not working. I don't know why. No error report is displayed.

```
public class CpassDao extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static boolean validate(String username,String password,String npass) {
        boolean status = false;
        ChangePass cp = new ChangePass();

        try {
            Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from doctable where username=? and password=?");

            ps.setString(1, username);
            ps.setString(2, password);

            ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery();
            status = rs.next();

            if(true) {
                PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement("update details set password=? where username=?");
                ps1.setString(1, cp.getNpass());
                ps1.setString(2, cp.getUsername());
                ps1.executeUpdate();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

            return status;
        }

        return status;
    }
}
```

Comment: How cp is populated with relevant user?

Comment: I can't get you clear.

Answer (score 0):

cp is created but you failed to assign it with username or password, therefore the update will be on empty usernme.

BTW while do you have `if(true)` which is unnecessary ? do you mean to use `rs.hasNext()`?

Comment: I used cp under 'if' condition. with the help of status value, i am inserting the value into the table(changing the password value into the table)

Comment: What's  cp.getUsername() returning?

Comment: It returns the username which i retrieve from the form. All the process are successfully but it is not updating in the table. If any corrections, you may do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot commit command after update. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and the problem solved. Now the database is updated with the new data. After the if statement, instead of giving 
"ps1.setString(1, cp.getNpass());" i gave "ps1.setString(1, npass());". Thats all. Problem solved. Thanks for your suggestions friend.